# Isomorphic endomorphism algebras implies isogenous (for abelian varieties over finite fields)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties, finite-fields

$\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}} 
\newcommand{\End}{\mathrm{End}} 
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
I would like to know if the following is true:

> **Proposition A** : Let $A_1, A_2$ be two abelian varieties over a finite field $k$. If $\End_{\overline k}(A_1) \otimes_{\Z} \Q$ and $\End_{\overline k}(A_2) \otimes_{\Z} \Q$ are isomorphic (as $\Q$-algebras), then $A_1, A_2$ are isogenous over $\overline k$.

The converse holds: let $\phi : A_1 \to A_2$ be an isogeny of degree $m$. There is an isogeny $\psi : A_2 \to A_1$ such that $psi \circ \phi = [m]$ (see Poonen "Lectures on rational points", Proposition 4.1.19 ; this is not the dual isogeny!). Define a map $\End_{\overline k}(A_1) \otimes_{\Z} \Q   \to \End_{\overline k}(A_2) \otimes_{\Z} \Q$ via
$f   \longmapsto     \dfrac{1}{m}  \phi \circ f \circ \psi $.
It is an algebra isomorphism.

The result holds over $\mathbb C$, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158410/abelian-varieties-with-the-same-cm-type-are-isogenous) or [Prop. 1.2.17](http://iml.univ-mrs.fr/%7Ekohel/phd/thesis_wilson.pdf). It holds for elliptic curves over a finite field: the supersingular case can be proved "by hand", using Tate isogeny theorem, while the ordinary case follows from Deuring's work on CM (lifting, etc.).
Note that the curves do *not* need to be isogenous over the base field $k$. I skimmed through the paper *Endomorphisms  of  Abelian  Varieties  over  Finite  Fields* of Tate, but I did not find such a statement.

Maybe one could use Serre–Tate theory instead of Deuring, but it seems to be only available for ordinary abelian varieties. I am not aware of the details here anyway. If the claim does not hold, is there a suitable hypothesis to make it true?

Comment: Did you mean to assume $A_i$ have CM?

Comment: @Wojowu : Tate proved that any abelian variety over a finite field is a CM abelian variety (Prop. 16.27 in Moonen--Geer notes on Abelian Varieties).

Comment: There are examples of abelian varieties with isomorphic endomorphism algebras but different $p$-ranks (see e.g. arxiv.org/pdf/2003.05380.pdf, §5.6) and $p$-ranks are isogenous invariants. If they still have the same endomorphism algebras over $\bar{k}$, they will provide counter-examples.

Comment: @HYL : thanks! In fact, Example 5.19 therein gives an example of two geometrically simple abelian varieties of dimension 3 over $\Bbb F_2$ (https://www.lmfdb.org/Variety/Abelian/Fq/3/2/a_c_c, https://www.lmfdb.org/Variety/Abelian/Fq/3/2/d_f_h), which are not isogenous, but according to the LMFDB "All geometric endomorphisms are defined over $\Bbb F_{2}$" (namely the geometric endomorphism algebra is a CM number field of degree 6, http://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/6.0.679024.1)

Comment: Update: this question and the answer below gave rise to the following preprint https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.06432 :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a counterexample to  Proposition A provided by 8-dimensional abelian varieties $A_1$ and $A_2$ over a finite field $F_{p^2}$ where $p$ is any prime that is congruent to $1$ modulo $17$ (e.g., $p=103$). The corresponding endomorphism algebra is the $17$th cyclotomic field $E=Q(\zeta_{17})$. The congruence condition  means that $p$ splits completely in $E$. It is known that $E/Q$ is a cyclic extension, the class number of $E$ is $1$ (see ``Introduction to cyclotomic fields" by Larry Washington) and any proper subfield of $E$ is totally real (because $17$ is a Fermat prime).

Let $O_E$ be the ring of integers in $E$ and $\iota: E \to E$ be the complex conjugation, which is the only element of order 2 in the cyclic Galois group $G:=Gal(E/Q)$ of order 16=2^4. (In particular, every nontrivial subgroup of $G$ contains $\iota$.)

Let S be the 16-element set of maximal ideals $\mathfrak{P}$ of integers $O_E$ with residual characteristic $p$. The group $G$ acts freely transitively on the set $S$ of maximal ideals in $O_E$ and $\Pi_{\mathfrak{P}\in S}\mathfrak{P}=p \cdot O_E$. Let H be the set of ideals $\mathfrak{B}$ of $O_E$ such that $\mathfrak{B}\cdot \iota(\mathfrak{B})=p \cdot O_E$. The set $H$ has $2^8=16^2$ elements.  I claim that the natural action of $16$-element $G$ on $H$ is free. Indeed, if it's not free then there is $\mathfrak{B}\in H$ such that $\iota(\mathfrak{B})=\mathfrak{B}$ and therefore
$$p \cdot O_E=\mathfrak{B}\cdot \iota(\mathfrak{B})=\mathfrak{B}^2,$$
which implies that $p$ is ramified in $E$, which is not the case. So, the action is free and therefore $H$ consists of $16$ orbits of $G$.

Now let's construct Weil's $p^2$-numbers $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$, using $\mathfrak{B}_1, \mathfrak{B}_2 \in H$ that belong to different orbits of $G$.  Let $z_1, z_2 \in O_E$ be generators of ideals $\mathfrak{B}_1$ and $\mathfrak{B}_2$ respectively. Then both
$v_1=z_1 \iota(z_1)$ and  $v_2=z_2 \iota(z_2)$ are ``real" (i.e., $\iota$-invariant) generators of $p\cdot O_E$, i.e., there are exist units $u_1,u_2 \in O_E^*$ such that
$$v_1=p u_1, \ v_2=p u_2.$$
Clearly, both $u_1$ and $u_2$ are real totally positive. Now let us put
$$\pi_1=z_1^2/u_1 \in O_E, \ \pi_2=z_2^2/u_2\in O_E.$$
Clearly,
$$\pi_1\cdot \iota(\pi_1)=p^2=\pi_2\cdot \iota(\pi_2)$$
(recall that $\iota(u_1)=u_1$ and $\iota(u_2)=u_2$).  Taking into account that
$$\pi_1 O_E=\mathfrak{B}_1^2, \pi_2 O_E=\mathfrak{B}_2^2,$$
we conclude that $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are not Galois-conjugate (and the same is true for powers $\pi_1^m$ and $\pi_2^m$ for any positive integer $m$). Clearly,
$$\pi_1 \ne \iota(\pi_1), \ \pi_2 \ne \iota(\pi_2)$$
and therefore
$$Q(\pi_1)=E= Q(\pi_2).$$
Now if $A_1$ (resp. $A_2$) is a simple abelian variety over $F_{p^2}$ attached (by Honda-Tate) to $\pi_i$  then the center of the division algebra $End(A_i)\otimes Q$ is isomorphic to $E$.  Since $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ (and even their powers) are not Galois-conjugate then $A_1$ and $A_2$ are not isogenous over $F_{p^2}$ (and even over its algebraic closure). On the other hand, both $A_1$ and $A_2$ are obviously ordinary. Since they are simple, their endomorphism algebras are commutative, i.e., coincide with their centers and therefore both $End(A_1)\otimes Q$ and $End(A_2)\otimes Q$ are isomorphic to $E$, Hence,
$$\dim(A_1)=[E:Q]/2=\dim(A_2),$$
i.e., both $A_1$ and $A_2$ are $8$-dimensional and
$End(A_1)\otimes Q$ is isomorphic to $End(A_2)\otimes Q$.

Let me stress that both $A_1$ and $A_2$ remain simple over an algebraic closure of $F_{p^2}$ and their endomorphism algebras remain isomorphic to $E$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this extended answer! I am going to read it, but just a quick question: you are considering the _geometric_ endomorphism algebras, right (and not just the endomorphisms defined over $\mathbb F_{p^2}$)? Oh, I just saw that you mention this at the very end of your post. Because then your construction contradicts the other answer, if I understand correctly... !

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, you understand it correctly: it certainly contradicts. The source of a mistake in the other answer is an improper use of Tate's theorem. Indeed, this theorem describes the local $v$-adic (or $\mathfrak{P}$-)invariants of the division algebra of endomorphisms. While these invariants lie in $Q/Z$, the other answer tacitly (and erroneously) assumes that they are rational numbers.

Answer (score 5):

This is true if $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ are geometrically simple. We may suppose that $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ have all their endomorphisms defined over $k$. Let $\pi_{i}$ be the Frobenius endomorphism of $A_{i}$. Tate's theorem (see his 1968 Bourbaki talk) shows that the numbers $ord_{v}(\pi)/ord_{v}(q)$ are the same for both abelian varieties, and these numbers determine $\pi$ up to a root of $1$ (as an element of a number field) because they determine all of its valuations. Extending the field raises $\pi$ to a power, and so gets rid of a root of $1$. Now apply Tate's (1966) theorem.

Comment: If they're not geometrically simple, the endomorphism algebra splits as a product of matrix algebras over division algebras, and applying your argument to those division algebras seems to do the trick.

Comment: Your answer is not correct (please see Prof. Zarhin's comment below).